# Table for each region in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

There are four regions with more than one million records total. Should I create a table with a region column or a table for each region and combine them to get the top ranks?

If I combine all four regions, none of my columns will be unique so I will need to also add an `id` column for my primary key. Otherwise, `name`, `accountId` & `characterId` would be candidate keys or should I just add an `id` column anyways.

```
Table:
----------------------------------------------------------------
| name | accountId | iconId | level | characterId | updateDate |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Edit:**
Should I look into partitioning the table by `region_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all records are related to a particular region, a single database table in 3NF(e.g All-Regions) containing a  regionId along with other attributes should work.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer, as usually with database design, is "**It depends**".

First of all, (IMHO) a good primary key should belong to the database, not to the users :)
So, if `accountId` and `characterId` are user-editable or prominently displayed to the user, they should not be used for the primary key of the table(s) anyway. And using `name` (or any other user-generated string) for a key is just asking for trouble.

As for the regions, try to divine how the records will be used.

- Whether most of the queries will use only a single region, or most of them will use data across regions?
- Is there a possibility that the schemas for different regions might diverge?
- Will there be different usage scenarios for similar data? (e.g. different phone number patterns for different regions)

Bottom line, both approaches will work, let your data tell you which approach will be more manageable.